# Circular Reference of MessageTypes for MessageField

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

In two of my message classes, I have two MessageFields that references each other. The server won't run this way, and in the meantime I've commented out one of the properties until I find a solution. Is there a Python solution to this problem?

```
class ChoiceMessage(messages.Message):

    code = messages.StringField(1, required=True)
    order = messages.IntegerField(2, required=True)
    text = messages.StringField(3, required=True)
    image = messages.EnumField(Image, 4)
    sub_question = messages.MessageField(QuestionMessage, 5)

class QuestionMessage(messages.Message):

    code = messages.StringField(1, required=True)
    type = messages.EnumField(Type, 2, required=True)
    order = messages.IntegerField(3, required=True)
    text = messages.StringField(4, required=True)
    choices = messages.MessageField(ChoiceMessage, 5, repeated=True)
```

Comment: Even if you could solve the circular reference - which the current code can't handle, I am pretty sure StructuredProperty will not let you do this.  You should re-design your model